# Number of choices of plus or minus such that this expression is $0$

Tags: combinatorics

Here is an interesting problem:

Let $N$ denote the number of $8$-tuples $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_8)$ of real numbers such that $a_1 = 10$ and

$\left|a_1^{2} - a_2^{2}\right| = 10$

$\left|a_2^{2} - a_3^{2}\right| = 20$

$\cdots$

$\left|a_7^{2} - a_8^{2}\right| = 70$

$\left|a_8^{2} - a_1^{2}\right| = 80$

Determine the remainder obtained when $N$ is divided by $1000$.

The answer to the problem is $472$ (and the number of tuples is obviously greater than $1000$ by the problem statement), but when I solve it I get only $11$ solutions, which means I am doing something obviously wrong.

---

My solution:

We can call $a_1^2$ through $a_8^2$ by $b_1$ through $b_8$ and the only restriction is that the $b_i$'s are positive. We can express $b_1=100$, $b_2=100 \pm 10$, ...$b_5=100 \pm 10 \pm 20 \pm 30 \pm 40$ and also $b_8=100 \pm 80$. Note that $b_7$ is either $90,110,250$. Note that regardless of how we choose these $\pm$'s all the $b_i$'s I've listed are positive so no restrictions are imposed here. There are restrictions imposed by $b_6$ being equal to $b_7 \pm 60$. We can now write $b_7/(10) \pm 6=b_6/(10)=10 \pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5$ so the only restrictions are imposed by $10 \pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5 \pm 6$ being equal to either $9,11,25$. If we find all the $\pm$ in this expression then $b_1$ through $b_8$ are all determined. We can reformulate now as find the number of choices of $\pm$ signs in the expression below:

$\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5 \pm 6$

which equals either $-1,1,15$.

If the expression equals $15$ then note that $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5$ is at most 15 so we must have $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5=9$, which forces $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 =4$ which forces $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 =0$ for which there are two possibilities of signs.

Now if the expression equals $1$ its symmetric to the case where it equals $-1$ so lets just consider

$\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4 \pm 5 \pm 6=1$

The signs in $\pm 5 \pm 6$ cannot both be positive. If they are both negative we get $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4=10$ and there is obviously $1$ choice here only. Otherwise $\pm 5 \pm 6=\pm 1$ so

$\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4=0$

or

$\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 \pm 4=2$

The latter case means $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 =6$ (obviously 1 choice) or $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3 =2$ (1 choice). Thus $2$ choices total for the latter case. In the former case the number of choices is twice the number of choices for $\pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3=4$ which forces $\pm 1 \pm 2=1$ for which there is 1 choice. Thus 2 choices total for the former case. Thus the number of choices when the expression equals $1$ is $1+2+2=5$. So the answer is $2*5+1=11$.

---

Several things:

1. I must have gone wrong in the beggining (where?)

2.Is there a faster/easier method with less casework?

3. The problem is related to finding the number of choices of $\pm$ signs such that $\pm 1+\pm 2 \pm +.... \pm n=0$, which seems difficult to solve. This must be a well-known problem. Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

First, when you go from a solution of $b$'s to a solution of $a$'s, there are seven square roots, so each solution of $b$'s becomes $128$ solutions of $a$'s.  We can use that to get the full number if we believe the answer key.  If there are $n$ solutions for the $b$'s, we want $128n \equiv 472 \pmod {1000}$  This has a [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=128*n%3D1000*m%2B472) for $n=74+125k$, so the answer key claims there are $74$ solutions for $b$'s and $9472$ solutions for $a$.  I don't believe it.  Your casework looks generally good, but it is not clear that you don't go negative in some solutions.  I believe it is true, but with only $11$ solutions it would be good to list them all.

For the general case,  I would just found the answer for small cases from a program and found [OEIS A063865](http://oeis.org/A063865) but that doesn't worry that your $b$'s might go negative along the way.  There are $14$ solutions to the sum for eight terms.  They are $59,60,87,90,102,105,112,143,150,153,165,168,195,196$ where you express them in binary, take the one bits as plus signs and zero bits as minus.  The ones bit in binary corresponds to adding or subtracting $1$.